# Difficulty understanding Floquet multipliers wrt Mathieu equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have the system

$$\begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}' = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ a-2\epsilon \cos t & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

and from Abel's formula we have that $\det \Phi(T) = 1$ if we choose $\Phi(0) = I$

We also know that the characteristic multipliers solve

$$\mu^2 - \text{tr}(\Phi(T))\mu + \det \Phi(T) = 0$$

Defining $2\phi := \text{tr}(\Phi(T))$, we get $\mu^2 - 2\phi \mu + 1 = 0$ and

$$\mu = \phi \pm \sqrt{\phi^2-1}$$

Starting with different values of $\phi$, we can then investigate stability. What I'm confused about is how we go from the initial parameters $a$ and $\epsilon$ to the value of $\phi = \text{tr}(\Phi(t))$. We kind of sped past Floquet theory in this class, so I've clearly missed something important. How do we find $\Phi(t)$ here?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I'm stuck pretty much at the same spot. Books and documents I have been reading describe a lot about the properties of characteristic multiplier, but haven't clearly mentioned how to obtain them for Mathieu's equation